# When does PostgreSQL write logs?

Tags: postgresql

I turned on the configuration parameter log_planner_stats and would like to examine the details in log. But the log file is empty. It seems all the log files are changed at 12:00am of a day. Does PostgreSQL only writes log at that time? Is there any way to see the real-time log? BTW, I checked the log files in the directory pg_log which I guess is the right directory to find logs.

Answer (score 2):

No, if PostgreSQL writes logs, then it writes basically real-time.  For example, if you open a log file with `less` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, you will get the newly written rows flowing in.

That you don't see anything in the logs can be caused by a few things, but first be sure you have read through the relevant [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and set up everything accordingly.  There and in `postgresql.conf` you can also check where the DB writes the logs and so on.  Be aware that some configuration options need server restart or DB reload to take effect.

Comment: What do you mean by "with less"?

Comment: :) the grey background and typewriter font are used to reflect that the test is either a piece of code or a command.  `less` is the linux `less` command.